# CakePHP 3 - How to add to an already set view var of type array

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm building a RESTful API which is returning a JSON response. When setting the view vars in the controller, is there a way to explicitly set elements of an array variable which already exists?

For example, let's say the `AppController` sets a view var which is an array:

```
$this->set('myArray', array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

But then in the child controller `MyController` I want to add to that array. Something like:

```
$this->set('myArray.add', 'New Element');
```

So that the JSON response for the view will be:

```
{
    "myArray": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "add": "New Element"
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it can be done in a roundabout way by storing the array as a normal PHP property of the `AppController` class, and then adding to the array in the child controller before finally doing `$this->set()` once at the end of the controller action.

But I'm curious if there is a way to do this through the `Controller::set()` method alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm curious if there is a way to do this through the Controller::set() method alone.

No. In such a case reading the code is always a good idea. This would have answered your question.

See http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.View.ViewVarsTrait.html#129

Implement a method like setMerge() that does what you want or directly array_merge() your data into the viewVars property in your controller.